# tkinter canvas object tag_bind

Tags: object, canvas, tkinter, tags, bind

I can't understand why I am getting no reaction to the tag_bind in code below: just want to get a handle on the tag_bind in order to elaborate on the event handler later. Nothing happens, and tkinter does not complain either. Thks for help.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
size = input("Choose a grid size eg. 4, 7, 12 ...: ")
size = int(size)
def create_grid():
    d = 20                      
    x0 = 20                     
    x1 = x0 + d
    y0 = 20                     
    y1 = y0 + d
    for i in list(range(size)):
        for j in list(range(size)):
            row = i
            col = j
            id = cv.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1,
                                 tags="ALL",fill="white")
            x0 = x1
            x1 += d
        x0 = d
        x1 = x0 + d
        y0 = y1
        y1 = y0 + d 
    id = cv.create_oval(24, 24, 36, 36, tags=("ALL","oval"),fill="yellow")
def oval_move(event):
    print(event.keysym)
cv = tk.Canvas(root, bd=5, relief="groove")
cv.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
cv.bind('<Configure>', create_grid())
cv.focus_set()           # probably not needed
cv.tag_bind("oval", '<KeyPress-Down>', oval_move)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

"keyboard focus" is what allows tkinter to know which object to send key events to. By default items on a canvas do not have keyboard focus. So, the first problem is that your oval won't see the key release because it doesn't have keyboard focus.

The second problem is that the only items on a canvas that can accept keyboard focus are text items. It's impossible to attach keyboard events to individual canvas items other than text objects. If you want non-text objects to react to key bindings, you must put the bindings on the canvas as a whole and then give the canvas the keyboard focus.

Comment: Ok. I inserted "cv.bind('<KeyPress-Down>',oval_move) before "cv.focus_set()" and that is all it took for the handler to react. But I did not and do not see the canvas bind requirement you pointed out documented anywhere. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
`tcv.bind(...)`
Instead of:
`tcv.tag_bind(...)`

Comment: Why does this work? Could you provide some more information?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no function tcv.tag_bind(...), but I know about tcv.bind(...). That's it